# Chart.js 2.x animation onComplete not responding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm trying to set a function for an animation callback of a chart. So far my options object looks like this:

```
$scope.chartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        datasetFill: false,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Title",
            fontSize: 14
        },
        tooltips: { mode: 'label' },
        animation: {
            onComplete: function(animation){
                $log.debug('onComplete');
            },
            onProgress: function(animation) {
                $log.debug('onProgress');
            }
        }
}
```

See, there I have animation onComplete and onProgress that don't work. However if I set the global Chart configuration it works properly.

```
Chart.defaults.global.animation.onProgress = function() { $log.debug('onprogress') };
```

It seems like it's a simple mistake, but I just can't see it! I'm referring to the animation callbacks correct? I don't won't to set it on globals, so I can have different behaviours for different charts.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Also, using the global way I can't access the chart instance. Like:

```
onComplete: function(animation){
                 if(!this.savedImage) {
                     $scope.saveChartImage(this);
                     this.savedImage = true;
                 }
```

Comment: According to this example (https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/AnimationCallbacks/progress-bar.html) it looks like you're doing it right. How are you passing the `options` to the chart object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. I was passing `$scope.chartOptions` to a function to add attributes to it depending on some other parameters. I was doing this for several charts, so I cloned $scope.chartOptions and modified the cloned versions of it, to finally pass these clones to the charts' constructor.

The problem: In order to clone the object I was doing a shallow copy of the object, and as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184745/4047905), a shallow copy of a collection is a copy of the collection structure, not the elements. For this reason I was losing the onProgress and onComplete functions.

So I used `angular.copy($scope.chartOptions)`.